# Gauging community interest and feedback on packages

Tags: discussion, packages

I have developed a package that I *think* might be of general interest to a wide range of Mathematica users, and could lower the barrier to attracting new users. I am not certain that it is at the stage of development where it would be ready for submission to the Mathematica Package Repository, however. What I would really like to do is post it, along with some usage examples and explanations, and solicit feedback, both in terms of community interest and in terms of suggestions for improvement. I noticed that the Mathematica Package Repository says to come here with questions, so I guess I am mainly asking if this is an appropriate kind of post to make here.

Comment: I’m the one who wrote the text over at packagedata.net, but I did actually write ask in the chat room not on the main site. Here on the main site there are different rules that apply, so people will not like it. The chat, however, is a good place because there are no rules there and the people like me who are and have been involved with the site hang out there.

Comment: This is not the place to post a package for beta testing. This is a question and answer site. As C.E. says it might make a good chat room thread.

Comment: Thank you; that is the information I was looking for.

Comment: Releasing is like voting. Do it early and do it often. No reason not to simply release it now, as that way your beta testers will have an easier time finding it. As for how to *publicize* that you wrote a package...well there's no real good way other than asking and answering questions here or writing a post for WC. Of course, much better to ask and answer questions here, because WC doesn't get the same quantity or quality of traffic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the topic of your package?

Comment: @ChrisK: The general-purpose package, called ComplexSymbols, provides a mechanism to turn anything you can format in a string into a symbol, both for input and output cells, allowing much more natural notation. My particular application is chemistry, and I am developing a set of packages that will rely on ComplexSymbols that handle chemical reactions, kinetics, stoichiometry, thermodynamics, complex equilibria, and so on, all in standard chemistry notation, but the enabling technology of complex symbols is applicable to pretty much any field.